# save pandas data frame as 32-bit float

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data in pandas which I'm trying to save as 32-bit float but instead I'm always getting 64-bit float. My best attempt was this:

```
df['store'] = pd.DataFrame(data).astype(float32)
```

but it's not working.. any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `numpy.float32`:

```
In [320]:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randn(10)})
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 1 columns):
a    10 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes

In [323]:   
df['a'].astype(np.float32)

Out[323]:
0    0.966618
1   -0.331942
2    0.906349
3   -0.089582
4   -0.722004
5    0.668103
6    0.230314
7   -1.707631
8    1.806862
9    1.783765
Name: a, dtype: float32
```

You can see that the dtype is now `float32`

Answer (score 1):

There is now a simpler solution than the accepted answer, without needing to import numpy:

```
.astype('float32')
```

Examples:

```
df['store'] = pd.DataFrame(data).astype('float32') 

df['rating'] = (df['rating']/2).astype('float32')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just extending on the accepted answer.  Note that if memory is constrained or you want more space, you can choose `df['a'].astype(np.float32)` as the answer gives or equally substitute `np.float16`, or `np.float64` for numbers, `np.int16`, `np.int32`, `np.int64` for integers,   Many applications you can take down to `int16` / `float16` and shrink your data footprint if accuracy is fine for your application.

Answer (score 0):

I had to convert all numerical columns to 32-bit and doing it individually isn't scalable. Here's another approach using [pd.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) -

```
# Creating an example DF
int_values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
text_values = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma", "delta", "epsilon"]
float_values = [0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0]
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "int_col": int_values,
    "text_col": text_values,
    "float_col": float_values
})

print(df)
   int_col text_col  float_col
0        1    alpha       0.00
1        2     beta       0.25
2        3    gamma       0.50
3        4    delta       0.75
4        5  epsilon       1.00
```

```
df1 = df.apply(
    func=lambda x: pd.to_numeric(arg=x, errors="ignore", downcast="float"),
    axis=0)

print(df1)
   int_col text_col  float_col
0      1.0    alpha       0.00
1      2.0     beta       0.25
2      3.0    gamma       0.50
3      4.0    delta       0.75
4      5.0  epsilon       1.00
```

You can check the original df and converted df2 with [pd.info()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html?highlight=info#pandas.DataFrame.info)

```
print(df.info(), df1.info())
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   int_col    5 non-null      int64    <--
 1   text_col   5 non-null      object 
 2   float_col  5 non-null      float64  <--
dtypes: float64(1), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 248.0+ bytes
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------     --------------  -----  
 0   int_col    5 non-null      float32  <--
 1   text_col   5 non-null      object 
 2   float_col  5 non-null      float32  <--
dtypes: float32(2), object(1)
memory usage: 208.0+ bytes
None None
```